# Which shell command is open android sqlite table in Command prompt

Tags: android

I am using sqlite in my application.I Check Eclipse DDMS the database is created.How to check wheather the table is created or not in command prompt.pls tell shell command of open database and open table in command prompt..........

Comment: Is this on the emulator? If not, is your phone rooted?

Answer (score 1):

cd to your data base directory

$ sqlite3 yourdb.db

> .schema;

or

> select * from yourtable;

use '.quit ' back to command prompt

'.help' also help you